# When I use window.location.href ,then my another function not calling .Following is my javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I am using Following code..

1. When I click on the link, the javascript `Hello()` function is invoked
2. I want to use `window.location.href`
3. But when I use this the following  `__doPostBack('Button2_Click')`, it does not work.
4. But when remove `window.location.href` from the following code then `__doPostBack('Button2_Click')` does work.

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript">

       function Hello(clicked_id) {
           var abc = "http://localhost:2621/OrgChart.aspx?id" + clicked_id;
           window.location.href = abc;
           __doPostBack('Button2_Click');

           return false;
       }

   </script>

   <a id="A1" href="javascript:Hello();">LINK</a>
   ```

This is my code behind code...

```
  public partial class WebForm17 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);//This is important to make the "__doPostBack()" method, works properly 

        if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "Button2_Click")
        {
            //call the method 
            Button2_Click(this, new EventArgs());
        } 

    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Label1.Text = "Method called!!!";
        EmpInfo emp = new EmpInfo();
        DA_EmpInfo da_emp = new DA_EmpInfo();
        List<EmpInfo> lei = da_emp.GetAllEmployeeInfoByEmpId("MJ-IB-1");
        DetailsView1.DataSource = lei;
        DetailsView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: window.location.href change page so any function async currently running on page will be aborted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, `__doPostBack` is making a request to the server and you break it by using `window.location.href = abc;`.

You should use some callback from this request to redirect to your url.

Comment: How can i use call back..to redirect my url

Comment: @UditSharma i don't know asp.net but check DOC, __doPostBack() method should accept callback (complete or success)

Answer (score 1):

try to use `setTimeOut` function

```
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = abc;
        }, 1000);
```

this will wait 1 second for finish of `__doPostBack()` function.

Or if you don't want to use timeOut, paste `window.location.href = abc;` line to end of the `__doPostBack()` function.

Comment: No, never use any kind of timeout to wait for any async method to finish, use callback method instead

Comment: simplest way of solving problems which is caused by asynchronization

Comment: Or can bring some bug really hard to catch. What would happen if request takes more than 1 second to complete?

Comment: You right but It's not important for casual, small requests. If this small request make more than 1 second to complete, there is another problem at somewhere try to solve that problem.